# Custom user model vs. additional model

Tags: django, django-authentication

Due to lack of knowledge, when faced with the need to store additional information about users, I created additional `UserInfo` model and referenced it by foreign key to the standard `User` model.

I have since learned two things:

1. It is recommended to have a custom user model.
2. It is tricky to switch mid-project ([this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313#comment:24) being the best way so far as far as I understand).

I would like to understand:

1. If the fields in `UserInfo` are not used for authentication, is there any reason to merge those into the user model?
2. What do I stand to gain by taking the time to abandon my current approach and switch to a custom user model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `UserInfo` model is not required for authentication, then there's no need to create a completely custom `User` model.

What you're currently doing is fine.

But instead of using `ForeignKey`, use `OneToOneField` so that one `UserInfo` instance is tied to one and only one `User` instance.

This method is also shown in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model.